# Toggling image onclick event inline

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, inline

Managed with the snippet below to change from the first image to the second image using the inline onclick javascript event. My question is; is there a way to change the second image back to first image when clicking on the second image with another inline Javascript event? ie. without writing a function.

`<img class="first-image" src="/first-image.png" onclick="this.src=\'/second-image.png\'" alt="my images">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your code like this:

```
<img class="first-image" src="/first-image.png" onclick="this.src==='/first-image.png' ? this.src='/second-image.png' : this.src='/first-image.png'" alt="my images">
```

Here is  a working example:

```html
<img class="first-image" src="https://photo-works.net/images/europe-landscape-photo-edited.jpg" onclick="this.src==='https://photo-works.net/images/europe-landscape-photo-edited.jpg' ? this.src='https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/landscape-nature-mountan-alps-rainbow-76824355.jpg' : this.src='https://photo-works.net/images/europe-landscape-photo-edited.jpg'" alt="my images">
```

Comment: This works but only if I can add the full image path.

Answer (score 0):

You could store both urls as properties of image tag, like this:

```
<img
  src="/first-image.png"
  data-src-1="/first-image.png"
  data-src-2="/second-image.png"
  onclick="this.src = this.src === this.getAttribute('data-src-1') ? this.getAttribute('data-src-2') : this.getAttribute('data-src-1')"
/>
```

Comment: I tried adding this and swapping out image urls. I also escaped the ```''``` because it's a php file but still can't get it to work.

Comment: Here is working example: https://jsfiddle.net/5tpjf8ws/5/